# What is PrintWriter out = response.getWriter() in a Servlet?

Tags: servlets, jersey, printwriter

I am new to Servlets.

Please, tell me about this line, and its use in the Jersey Framework + RESTful web services.

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

Answer (score 21):

In servlets the output can be either character or byte. for character data (i.e text)  u can use **PrintWriter** for others use **ServletOutputStream**

```
PrintWriter: prints text data to a character stream. 

getWriter :Returns a PrintWriter object that can send character text to the client.
```

Answer (score 6):

in this case,
the servlet binded with the url-pattern (previously set) is called.

The method being called depends on the kind of request (doGet, doPost, doPut).

The method normally receives the request and response objects, we then call the .getWriter() method for the response obj that gets us the stream on which we can write our output.

response.getWriter() returns a PrintWriter object that can send character text to the client.

Calling flush() on the PrintWriter commits the response.

Answer (score 6):

Simple just have a look again

```
Printwriter out = response.getWriter()
```

Now, here Printwriter is a class which simply converts the bytes into normal characters which we want to show as a response to the client's browser.So first you define `out` as a Printwriter object and through the GetWriter method we get the instance.

Answer (score 5):

res.getWriter(); 
returns the object of PrintWriter Class, 
in which print(String args) method is declared to print anything on the browser's page as a response.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple you see print writer is actually a class of servlet it gets response from app server to the real server using the get writer method and uses out as object

Comment: Everything happens in web container only and it's http specific

Answer (score -2):

`PrintWriter=respose.getWriter();` use to print at server `.getWriter()` returns character text to the client. The java `PrintWriter` class belong `java.io.PrintWriter`. For intances writing `int`, `long`, and other primitive data formatted as text rather as their byte value.

Answer (score -4):

dnt be confused 
its simple as 
we had created object OUT of class PRINTWRITER nd simply returned as response by using GETWRITER METHOD.

Comment: Please be more specific with your answer, and use spell check.